# Difference between `with type` and functors in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Suppose the following module:

```
module type A = sig
  type a
  type f = r:a -> unit Lwt.t
end

module type AA = A with type a = B.t
```

Couldn't I make module `A` parametrized (turn it into a functor) that accepts `B.t` as a parameter?

```
module type A (b: B.t) = sig
  type f = r:b -> unit Lwt.t
end

module type AA = A(B.t)
```

Are these equivalents? Why there's 2 ways of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

> Are these equivalents? Why there's 2 ways of doing the same thing?

There isn't, and they aren't. Your "functor" isn't valid, which you could have easily found out by trying it out yourself.

Functors and module constraints (ie. `with type ...`) work in different domains. Functors work on implementations and module constraints work on signatures/types. Furthermore, module constraints take an existing signature and adds information to it (the constraint), while functors take a module implementation as a parameter, but does not extend it, or need the input and output signatures to have any relationship at all to each other.

You *can* use a functor to extend *implementations* generically, using `include` as explained before. But as the signature of the argument is static its reusability, and therefore its usefulness, is limited:

```
module A (B1: B) = struct
  include B
  let x = 42
end
```